# react application not able to read js file available in public folder

Tags: reactjs

I have copied js (handy.min.js) in my project's public directory

I included it in my index.html using %PUBLIC_URL%/handy.min.js

But this file not found when I run my application.

I created project using create-react-app.
No webpack specific config

Any suggestion how to make this file available after I run react build profile.pro

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to your index.html file:

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/handy.min.js" ></script>
```

further reading: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-files-in-public-folder-in-reactjs/